# DTO classes with generic types

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

We would like to use generic DTO contracts with a generic parameter T.
The generic type can be string, boolean, int or double.

Is there an 'out-of-the-box' solution to deserialize the JSON into the Entry again when calling the Web API in C# (frontend -> web api). In case it should be possible, can we have a web api request or response class containing a list of EntryDto where T can be string, boolean, int or double?

For example:

```
public class EntryDto<T> {
   public T Value { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: It *should* already just work, depending on what JSON you expect it to serialize to / deserialize from

Comment: _"containing a list of EntryDto where `T` can be string, boolean, int or double"_ -  if the list contains only "single" `T` then it should work out of the box with both main JSON handling libraries. If you want to have a list with multiple types (`T`'s) then you will have a problem before serialization - you will need to understand how to declare such list in the first place.

Comment: You can use generic DTOs with parameters such as string, boolean, int, or double. For instance, you can define an `EntryDto<T> class` to represent entries with a generic value. When handling Web API requests and responses, you can use classes like `ApiRequest<T>` and `ApiResponse<T>` containing lists of `EntryDto<T>`.

Comment: Well, it is the purpose to have a response that contains a list of EntryDto objects. For some items the T will be string, other items in that list we would like to use boolean as T, .... It works when T is object, but I am still experiencing issues when calling the web api from the frontend to deserialize it again. I guess I need some custom logic here?

Comment: Share those specific part where you are having those issues, without looking at, its hard to comment or suggest anything.